# Bugzilla restrict bug status

Tags: linux, bugzilla

We need a solution for one of our deployment in bugzilla.

Example of our scenario are as below :

**Group : Staff,Students**

**project/product bugs : projectA , projectB**

We need to know is there any way to :

1) Restrict the group of user from accessing the project.

```
Example= Students cannot access or view bugs in projectA.
```

2) Restrict other group of user from confirming or change the bug status

```
Example= Students cannot change the bug status of projectB  from  NEW to RESOLVED
```

3) Some members set of group can only file a bug but not close the file

```
Example= StaffA can only file a bug in ProjectA but cannot closed it whereas StaffB can file the bug and also can close the bug
```

From what I have search/Google, there are no documentation available which can explain this function in bugzilla.But maybe I have overlooked somehow.
Our current bugzilla is version **3.2rc1**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really say which version of Bugzilla you are using, so the URLs are for the latest release, 4.2. However, the same concepts apply to most recent versions. For instance, we use 3.6 and control whether certain users can change certain things in the same ways that I describe below.

1) Restricting users who are not in a group from seeing bugs is what Bugzilla's group security does:

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/groups.html

One wrinkle in your case is that group security controls positive access rather than negative access. That is, it allows specifying which groups **can** view bugs in a product rather than groups that **cannot**. To keep members of `students` from viewing bugs in `projectA`, you'll need to have a group that can access `projectA` and devise a way to keep users in `students` out of that group.

Alternatively, you could put some custom code into `Bugzilla::User::can_see_bug`, `Bugzilla::User::visible_bugs`, or `Bugzilla::Bug::check_is_visible` to exert firmer control that users who are in group `students` can **never** see bugs in `projectA`

2) You can exercise a lot of granularity in allowing changes:

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/cust-change-permissions.html

We do something like this. We have a set of users to whom we want to grant read-only access unless we have explicitly allowed read-write access. To do this, we have a group called `allspecialusers` to which these users belong based on email address. We have another group called `approved_specialusers` to which some of those users are added manually.

So, in our `Bugzilla::Bug::check_can_change_field`, we have code like:

> ```
> if ($user->in_group('specialusers') &&
>     !$user->in_group('approved_specialusers')) {
>     $$PrivilegesRequired = 3;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

You can do what you want by checking if the bug is in product `projectB` and the user trying to make the change is in group `students`

Comment: hi thanks so much for your respond. you've really pinpoint my problem precisely.anyway I've already update another question above.I really appreciate if you can help me with it.